# How to close/hide previously opened ul li in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build custom accordion type navigation menu in which when we click on parent list item then its nested ul li items are displayed. They are hidden when we click again on its parent li item. But one thing which is creating problem is I also want to close or hide any previously opened ul list items if any. I don't know how to make it perfect - my solutions are not working 100% correct.

My code is:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header_wrapper"> <!-- HEADER WRAPPER STARTS -->

    <div id="header"> <!-- HEADER STARTS -->

        <div id="logo"> <!-- LOGO STARTS -->
            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="responsive" /></a>
        </div> <!-- LOGO ENDS -->

    <div id="nav_wrapper"> <!-- NAVIGATION WRAPPER STARTS -->

            <div id="menu_icon_wrapper">
                <div id="menu_icon"></div>
            </div>

        <div id="nav_bar"> <!-- NAVIGATION BAR STARTS -->

            <ul id="nav"> <!-- NAVIGATION STARTS -->
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul> <!-- NAVIGATION ENDS -->

        </div> <!-- NAVIGATION BAR ENDS -->

    </div> <!-- NAVIGATION WRAPPER ENDS -->

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div> <!-- HEADER ENDS -->

</div> <!-- HEADER WRAPPER ENDS -->
```

**CSS**

```
#header_wrapper {
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
}

#header {
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px 0;
    position:relative;
}

#logo {
    /*float:left;*/
}


#nav_bar {
    position:relative;
    z-index:99999;
    background-color:#F34744;
}

#nav_bar ul li a {
    background-color:#F34744;
    border-top:1px solid #EE312D;
    padding:6px 12px;
    display:block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:14px;
    outline:none;
    text-align:left;
}

#nav_bar ul li a:hover,
#nav_bar ul li a.active {
    background-color:#EE312D;
}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a {
    text-indent:25px;
    background-color:#F45d5A;
}

#nav_bar ul li ul {
    display:none;
}

#nav_bar ul li ul.inner_dd {
    display:block;
}

/* main nav */
ul#nav {
    display:none; /* visibility will be toggled with jquery */
}

/* menu icon */
#menu_icon_wrapper {
    position:relative;
    height:24px;
}

#menu_icon {
    background-color:blue;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-21px;
    right:-1px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#menu_icon:hover {
    /*background-color:#dd7d06;*/
}

#menu_icon.active {
    /*background-color:#EE312D;*/
}

@media only screen and (min-width:900px) {

#header_wrapper {
    border-top:5px solid yellow;
}

#nav_wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:40px;
    right:0;
}

#menu_icon_wrapper {
    display:none; /* hide menu icon initially */
}

/* Ensure #nav is visible on desktop version */
ul#nav {
    display:block !important;
}

#nav_bar ul li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:35px;
}

#nav_bar ul li a
{
    border-top:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:0;
    color:#666666;
    display:block;
    font-size:15px;
}

#nav_bar ul li:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}

#nav_bar ul li a.active,
#nav_bar ul li a:hover {
    color:#000000;
    background-color:transparent;
}

#nav_bar ul li a.active {
    /*border-bottom:2px solid #EE312D;*/
}

/* dropdown menu */

#nav_bar ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:24px;
    border:1px solid #666666;
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
}

/* Display dropdown menu on hover */

#nav_bar ul li ul.inner_dd {
    display:none;
}

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {
    display:block; 
}

#nav_bar ul li ul li {
    float:none;
    z-index:99999;
    margin-right:0;
}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a {
    text-indent:inherit;
    background-color:transparent;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding:0 10px;
    font-size:14px;
}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}

}
```

**jQuery**

```
// Toggle navigation
$("#menu_icon").on("click", function(){
    $("ul#nav").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});

// Show/hide dropdown menu
$("ul#nav li a").click(function(e){
    if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length != 0)
    {
        if($(window).innerWidth() < 900)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).siblings('ul').toggleClass('inner_dd');
        }
    }
});
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/coder07/jj2mLbp0/4/) my so far working code in working action.

In demo, when you click on blue square, then drop down menu appears. I want "item 1" to be closed when we open "item 3" and vice-versa. Similar action for other menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```js
var nav = $("ul#nav"),
  subNavs = nav.children('li').children('ul');

// Toggle navigation
$("#menu_icon").on("click", function() {
  nav.slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});

// Show/hide dropdown menu
$("ul#nav li a").click(function(e) {
  var anchor = $(this),
    subNav = anchor.next("ul");

  if (subNav.length != 0 && $(window).innerWidth() < 900) {
    e.preventDefault();
    subNav.toggleClass('inner_dd');
    subNavs.not(subNav).removeClass('inner_dd');
  }
});
```

```css
 #header_wrapper {
   background-color: red;
   width: 100%;
 }
 
 #header {
   max-width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 10px 0;
   position: relative;
 }
 
 #logo {
   /*float:left;*/
 }
 /* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
  TOP NAVIGATION
   
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 
 #nav_bar {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 99999;
   background-color: #F34744;
 }
 
 #nav_bar ul li a {
   background-color: #F34744;
   border-top: 1px solid #EE312D;
   padding: 6px 12px;
   display: block;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 14px;
   outline: none;
   text-align: left;
 }
 
 #nav_bar ul li a:hover,
 #nav_bar ul li a.active {
   background-color: #EE312D;
 }
 
 #nav_bar ul li ul li a {
   text-indent: 25px;
   background-color: #F45d5A;
 }
 
 #nav_bar ul li ul {
   display: none;
 }
 
 #nav_bar ul li ul.inner_dd {
   display: block;
 }
 /* main nav */
 
 ul#nav {
   display: none;
   /* visibility will be toggled with jquery */
 }
 /* menu icon */
 
 #menu_icon_wrapper {
   position: relative;
   height: 24px;
 }
 
 #menu_icon {
   background-color: blue;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 45px;
   height: 45px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -21px;
   right: -1px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 #menu_icon:hover {
   /*background-color:#dd7d06;*/
 }
 
 #menu_icon.active {
   /*background-color:#EE312D;*/
 }
 /* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 MEDIA QUERIES FOR A RESPONSIVE LAYOUT (MOBILE FIRST)
  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 /* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 LARGER THAN 900
  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 
 @media only screen and (min-width:900px) {
   #header_wrapper {
     border-top: 5px solid yellow;
   }
   #nav_wrapper {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 40px;
     right: 0;
   }
   #menu_icon_wrapper {
     display: none;
     /* hide menu icon initially */
   }
   /* Ensure #nav is visible on desktop version */
   ul#nav {
     display: block !important;
   }
   #nav_bar ul li {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     margin-right: 35px;
   }
   #nav_bar ul li a {
     border-top: none;
     background-color: transparent;
     padding: 0;
     color: #666666;
     display: block;
     font-size: 15px;
   }
   #nav_bar ul li:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
   }
   #nav_bar ul li a.active,
   #nav_bar ul li a:hover {
     color: #000000;
     background-color: transparent;
   }
   #nav_bar ul li a.active {
     /*border-bottom:2px solid #EE312D;*/
   }
   /* dropdown menu */
   #nav_bar ul li ul {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 24px;
     border: 1px solid #666666;
     background-color: #F8F8F8;
   }
   /* Display dropdown menu on hover */
   #nav_bar ul li ul.inner_dd {
     display: none;
   }
   #nav_bar ul li:hover ul {
     display: block;
   }
   #nav_bar ul li ul li {
     float: none;
     z-index: 99999;
     margin-right: 0;
   }
   #nav_bar ul li ul li a {
     text-indent: inherit;
     background-color: transparent;
     display: block;
     white-space: nowrap;
     padding: 0 10px;
     font-size: 14px;
   }
   #nav_bar ul li ul li a:hover {
     background-color: #EEEEEE;
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header_wrapper">
  <!-- HEADER WRAPPER STARTS -->

  <div id="header">
    <!-- HEADER STARTS -->

    <div id="logo">
      <!-- LOGO STARTS -->
      <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <!-- LOGO ENDS -->

    <div id="nav_wrapper">
      <!-- NAVIGATION WRAPPER STARTS -->

      <div id="menu_icon_wrapper">
        <div id="menu_icon"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="nav_bar">
        <!-- NAVIGATION BAR STARTS -->

        <ul id="nav">
          <!-- NAVIGATION STARTS -->
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- NAVIGATION ENDS -->

      </div>
      <!-- NAVIGATION BAR ENDS -->

    </div>
    <!-- NAVIGATION WRAPPER ENDS -->

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

  </div>
  <!-- HEADER ENDS -->

</div>
<!-- HEADER WRAPPER ENDS -->
```

Comment: Wow! you exactly did what I required. Btw you changed my code logic.

Answer (score 0):

you just could do this:

```
$("ul#nav li a").click(function(e){
    if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length != 0)
    {
        if($(window).innerWidth() < 900)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('ul').removeClass('inner_dd');
            $(this).siblings('ul').toggleClass('inner_dd');
        }
    }
});
```

you may add a class to each 'ul' element. this allows you just remove the `inner_dd` class from the 'ul' elements you want:

e.g.:

```
<ul class="myclass">...</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.myclass').removeClass('inner_dd');
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4t006rpg/2/

Comment: Though you managed to hide previously opened sub nav but current opened main nav can't be hidden again even clicking on it. That would mess!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the class `inner_dd` from the other li elements add this piece of code to do the same

```
   $('ul').removeClass('inner_dd')
```

Complete jquery code

```
            // Toggle navigation
    $("#menu_icon").on("click", function(){
        $("ul#nav").slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Show/hide dropdown menu
    $("ul#nav li a").click(function(e){
        if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length != 0)
        {
            if($(window).innerWidth() < 900)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
      $('ul').removeClass('inner_dd')
                $(this).siblings('ul').toggleClass('inner_dd');
            }

        }
    });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jj2mLbp0/6/)**

Comment: I did not read his solution. Maybe we posted at the same time because the answerd time is showing the same for both of us

Comment: Yeah I had already noticed that. Could you managed to hide current opened main list?